# Cannot find record in table after upgrading mysql from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7

We recently upgraded our database from mysql 5.6 to 5.7 and started seeing a new error that happens to occur intermittently. The error happens while trying to access results of a query or while getting the total count. The error message that comes back looks like `Can't find record in tablename`. The same query works perfectly fine when tried again almost immediately. Also, we are only seeing this issue in production which makes me think if we are missing some config while upgrading to Mysql 5.7. Please let me know if you need other specific information since I'm not sure what all would help at this point.

Comment: *The error message that comes back looks like `Can't find record in tablename.`* This may be a result of tables structure or indices unsuccessfull upgrade. Try to repair a table and re-create its indices.

Comment: Did you run mysql_upgrade command after the upgrade?

Comment: We used AWS' DMS to replicate the data from previous 5.6 aurora cluster to the newer 5.7 cluster and then promoted one of the newer reader to a writer.